# Using javascript to alter element's CSS display property works inconsistently on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got what should be a fairly simple "please wait" overlay that should pop up during a variety of different tasks on a data-review/dashboard website I'm working on (data queries, chart rendering using ChartJS, putting data into a file for download, etc.) that is not consistently working as desired in Chrome.

I toggle the overlay via Javascript at the beginning and end of each function that I need it for. The overlay successfully displays/turns off on IE11 and Firefox every time I do a function that calls it, but on Chrome it is consistently inconsistent (ALWAYS displays during specific functions, NEVER displays during other functions) despite calling the same few lines of code every time. When it does not display, the console confirms that the method to toggle it is being called and I can see the page's HTML update, ***but the user's display does not change.***

The functions that the overlay does not display for involve creating/updating ChartJS charts, including an AJAX call to get data. I have functions that the overlay displays properly on that involve just doing AJAX requests. On the functions where it does not display, it never shows up on the user's screen at all, even well before I get to ChartJS stuff. It's confusing as heck. I can give out a little of that code if it would be useful, but again since the overlay never even shows despite toggling the overlay as the first line of those functions, I don't think that's the the problem...

It's a style thing more than a function thing; I also disable other user-interface elements while the overlay is supposed to be active (**which Chrome's display also does NOT reflect but again definitely occurs**). But I'd still like the overlay to consistently display, particularly since those ChartJS functions can take a few seconds, and I'm wondering if people have any ideas.

HTML for overlay, as it appears on page-load

```
<div id="overlay">
    <img src="img/loader.gif"></img><br><strong>Data loading, please wait</strong>
    <div id="overlayAdditonalMesages">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript for overlay toggle

```
function overlayToggleOn(additionalMsg) {
  console.log("overlay should be on");
  document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = '<img src="img/loader.gif"></img><br><strong>Data loading, please wait</strong>'+additionalMsg;
  document.getElementById("overlay").setAttribute("style", "display: flex;");
  $("overlay").show(); //just trying to fix the thing with Chrome
}

function overlayToggleOff() {
  console.log("overlay should be off");
  document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = '<img src="img/loader.gif"></img><br><strong>Data loading, please wait</strong>';
  document.getElementById("overlay").removeAttribute("style");
}
```

Like I said, should be simple, and I struggle to understand why it's not working consistently in Chrome. Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: `$("overlay").show()` should be `$("#overlay").show()`

Comment: also `overlayToggleOn(additionalMsg) { if ( ! additionalMsg ) { console.log('additionalMsg is missing'); return; }` might help :)

Comment: `.setAttribute("style", "display: flex;");` why set an attribute? Set the style directly. Or event better,  just toggle a class on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Why using `.setAttribute()` for you inline styles.
I also saw where you added a closing tag for your image element `</img>` why?

Use

```
id.style.property = value
```

Instead of `setAttribute()`